# bash: variable not being expanded as expected

Tags: bash, shell

If I set a variable in a shell script and then try to use it to create another variable, it doesn't seem to get substituted correctly. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
X=/software/xxx
echo variable X = $X
echo path using variable: $X/yyy
echo path without variable: /software/xxx/yyy
```

This outputs:

```
variable X = /software/xxx
/yyy using variable: /software/xxx
path without variable: /software/xxx/yyy
```

I had expected the second output line to be:

```
path using variable: /software/xxx/yyy
```

I have tried various combinations of quotes and using ${X}, but all to no avail.

I'm new to shell scripting (coming from a Windows background), so I'm sure there is something really simple that I'm missing here.

In case anyone wonders why I want to do this, the background to this is that I need to write a shell script that takes a relative pathname parameter, determines its absolute pathname, then sets CLASSPATH with a number of jar files in that directory before invoking a Java program:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=`readlink -fn $1`
export CLASSPATH=$DIR/x.jar:$DIR/y.jar
java progname
```

Comment: Quoting is normally the reason of the problems in the world.

Comment: I just ran your example, and I get the expected output.  Try running with bash -x and seeing what $X is set to.  I suspect X is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have carriage return (CR) character at the end of your `X=` variable declaration:

```
#!/bin/bash

X=/software/xxx^M
echo variable X = $X
echo path using variable: $X/yyy
```

(where `^M` represents ONE special character - CR). I assume your editor doesn't show it. Try to open your script with `vim`. Windows and Linux marks newline in a different way ([check wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)) . I suppose you're using some Windows editor.

Please read [Bash Pitfalls webpage](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls). I'm sure you can learn a lot from there.

btw. one way to enter `^M` at `vim`: go to insert-mode `i`, than press: `CTRL+k`, `M`, `ENTER`

Comment: You can also remove all `^M` characters from the file with `vim`: `:%s/^M$//`. Vim can be painful for beginners but `vimtutor` will make you love it.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers. There were indeed extra \r characters in the file. (I had prepared it on Windows using emacs - I dislike vi as an editor). bash -x revealed the situation. Have recreated the file from scratch on Linux and it worked just fine.

Comment: You can use `vi -b` to edit a file in "binary mode" which shows extra `^M` chars at the end when running on Linux.